# qt 4.8.2 qpa QGraphicsView ( QGLWidget ) rendering produces black screen

Tags: qt, opengl-es, lighthouse

I'm trying to render some simple qt application, that uses `QGraphicsView` with
`QGLWidget` as a `viewport` ( slightly modified collidingmice ) on `armv7 embedded platform`
( `beagleboard` ). Starting application like this:

```
collidingmice -platform eglfs
```

But screen is always remains dark. ( textures example is working fine ). 
Is qt lighthouse able to render painting throught opengles with platform like elgfs?
I can't find any precise information about it.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: It depends on your EGL implementation and on your windows system. What is it? I used the eglfs driver once on the framebuffer with slight modifications and it was working correctly.

Comment: I'm not using any window system. If you mean configuration in /etc/powervr.ini, i've used: _libpvrPVR2D_FRONTWSEGL.so (for direct writes to FrameBuffer - FRONT mode of operation - directly writes to FrameBuffer without waiting for vsync - fastest mode of operation)_

Comment: My answer still applies, something will have to provide a native window on the framebuffer.

Answer (score 1):

I just had a look to the sources [here](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/blobs/4.8/src/plugins/platforms/eglfs/qeglfsscreen.cpp). The driver is not making any assumptions on your windows system, so it is using 0 as the default native window handle, which is often correct. This may not be the case for your platform. You'll have to modify the sources so that the function eglCreateWindowSurface is passed a valid native window handle. I suspect that might be the reason of the black screen.

EDIT: I don't know what exactly that library libpvrPVR2D_FRONTWSEGL.so does, but according to the name that may be what will provide the native window on the framebuffer. Read the manual of that library.

EDIT2: That library provides in fact the Window System. Look here: http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/SGXDbg. You could also use Qt Embedded instead of Qt QPA as there is a working driver for the PowerVR: http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/trees/4.8/src/plugins/gfxdrivers/powervr.

Comment: Thank you for help. I understand the problem. We can't use `QWS`, because future implemetations of `Qt` don't have it. In qt5 we only have only `QPA` and `QWS` highly depends on `SGX SDK`.

Comment: Yes, Qt 5 won't include QWS, but you asked Qt 4.8.2. Anyway, the EGLFS driver should work on your platform if you provide that function the native window handle (assuming 0 is not correct on your platform). I did on mine and it worked. Anyway, it is possible other modifications are needed.

Comment: Can you tell me what hardware platform did you used?

Comment: Sorry, I can't provide that information. Yours is however more common and supported.

Comment: If i properly understand the functionality of libraries in Ti SDK, they are providing window system only for opengl applications. Nead to create some new window system plugin, like libQWSWSEGL.so. Or use Qt5, which says that supports working with libpvrPVR2D_FRONTWSEGL.so